# Deleting user-data-dir after execution done

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using remote web driver, Java and selenium 3.141.59 (both server and client). I have Chrome 79 and chrome driver 79. I was thinking selenium would delete the user-data-dirs automatically after the execution done but it seems it is not doing that. should I delete them manually?

My chrome options:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions ();
    options.addArguments ("user-data-dir=" + userDataDir);
    options.addArguments ("disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments ("disable-impl-side-painting");
    options.addArguments ("disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments ("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments ("disable-gpu-sandbox");
    options.addArguments ("no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments ("disable-accelerated-2d-canvas");
    options.addArguments ("disable-accelerated-jpeg-decoding");
    options.addArguments ("test-type=ui");
    options.addArguments ("no-proxy-server");
```

Comment: Use driver.close() before the driver.quit() in a test.

Comment: I am already calling it but not working.